# Assembler for Brookshear Machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, assembly

As a small exercise in Python, I created an Assembler for the rather simple Brookshear Machine (see f.e. [Brookshear Machine](https://brookshear.jfagerberg.me/#), please note, however, that the instruction set differs from mine).
The instruction set used by this implementation is based on a task from a friend's Computer Science course. He showed me another online emulator [here](http://joeledstrom.github.io/brookshear-emu/#12ff4004a103c000) which is compatible to the machine code generated by this assembler.

I'm open to any suggestions for improvement but do not have any specific question 
at hand because I'm quite satisfied how the module looks for the moment.

While typing, I realised I'd like to know if there's a better way to handle DEBUG messages in the code, so that I can quickly enable/disable all of them.

```py
'''Assembler for the Brookshear machine.

This is a module for assembling assembler code compatible to the Brookshear
Machine.
'''
from enum import Enum
from typing import List, Tuple

class OpType(Enum):
    '''The type of the operand's parameter

    The value of every enumeration's item is it's maximum allowed value.
    '''
    ZER = 0x0   # Zero (0)
    REG = 0xF   # Register address
    NIB = 0xF   # Non-restricted Nibble (4 bit)
    ADR = 0xFF  # Address


class Op(Enum):
    '''All the available operands in this Brookshear machine model.

    Every element of the enumeration is a single operand in this Brookshear
    machine and consists of a tuple with the following elements:
    1. The OpCode in machine code
    2. The OpTypes of the input parameters
    3. The order of the output parameters.
    '''
#   Mnemonic    Opcode  Input-Types                             output order
    LOAD        = (1,   [OpType.REG, OpType.ADR],               [0, 1])
    LOADI       = (2,   [OpType.REG, OpType.ADR],               [0, 1])
    STORE       = (3,   [OpType.ADR, OpType.REG],               [1, 0])
    MOVE        = (4,   [OpType.REG, OpType.REG],               [OpType.ZER, 1, 0])
    ADD         = (5,   [OpType.REG, OpType.REG, OpType.REG],   [0, 1, 2])
    ADD_FLOAT   = (6,   [OpType.REG, OpType.REG, OpType.REG],   [0, 1, 2])
    OR          = (7,   [OpType.REG, OpType.REG, OpType.REG],   [0, 1, 2])
    AND         = (8,   [OpType.REG, OpType.REG, OpType.REG],   [0, 1, 2])
    XOR         = (9,   [OpType.REG, OpType.REG, OpType.REG],   [0, 1, 2])
    ROTATE_RIGHT= (0xA, [OpType.REG, OpType.NIB],               [0, OpType.ZER, 1])
    JUMP        = (0xB, [OpType.ADR, OpType.REG],               [1, 0])
    HALT        = (0xC, [],                                     [OpType.ZER, OpType.ZER, OpType.ZER])

class Assembler:
    '''Assembler for given Brookshear machine model.'''
    commentSymb = ";"
    delimSymb = ","

    def __init__(self, code: str):
        self.code = code
        self.output = None

    def get_last_translation(self) -> str:
        '''Return the most recently translated program.

        If no program was created yet, return null.
        '''
        return self.output

    def translate(self) -> str:
        '''Translates the Brookshear Assembly Code to Brookshear Machine code.'''
        self.output = ""
        for num, line in enumerate(self.code.split("\n"), 1):
            print(f"[DEBUG] Processing: #{line}#")
            line = self.__preprocess_line(line)
            # If the line is empty, skip further processing.
            if len(line) == 0:
                continue
            decoded_line = self.__decode_instr(line)
            if not decoded_line[0]:
                # There was an error decoding the instruction... Display error
                # and add notice to output
                print(f"[ERROR] ({num}): {decoded_line[1]}")
                self.output += "[ERR]"
            else:
                # The assembling of the instruction was successful. Add it to
                # the output.
                print(f"[DEBUG] {decoded_line[1]}")
                self.output += decoded_line[1]

        return self.output

    def __preprocess_line(self, line: str) -> str:
        '''Preprocess a line from the given input.

        Strip any leading/trailing whitespace, remove any comments and convert
        all characters to uppercase.
        '''
        return line.strip().split(Assembler.commentSymb)[0].upper()

    def __decode_instr(self, line: str) -> Tuple[bool,str]:
        '''Decode a single instruction.

        As a first step, a line from the source file is scanned for a known Op-
        Code and handled accordingly.
        Return a tuple whose first element is 'False' if any error occured.
        '''
        print(f"[DEBUG] Decode: #{line}#")
        # A String representation of all available Ops
        op_list = [name for name, member in Op.__members__.items()]
        # HALT Operation needs no space after it
        if line.startswith("HALT"):
            return self.__validate_instr(Op.HALT, line)
        elif len(line.split(" ")) <= 1\
        or line.split(" ")[0].replace("-","_") not in op_list:
            return (False, f"No valid instruction found! - "\
            f"len={len(line.split(' '))}, instr={line.split(' ')[0]}")
        else:
            op = line.split(" ")[0].replace("-","_")
            return self.__validate_instr(Op[op], line)

    def __validate_instr(self, op: Op, instr: str) -> Tuple[bool,str]:
        '''Validate a single decoded instruction.

        Return a tuple whose first element is 'False' if any error occured.
        '''
        print(f"[DEBUG] Validate: <{op}> #{instr}#")
        # Remove Assembler-OpCode and whitespace
        instr = instr[len(op.name) + 1:].strip()
        expected_no_of_ops = len(op.value[1])
        # Compare length of expected operand list and actual operand list
        if expected_no_of_ops > 0 and\
        expected_no_of_ops != len(instr.split(Assembler.delimSymb)):
            return (False, f"Invalid number of operands for Instr. {op.name}:"\
            f" Expected: {expected_no_of_ops}"\
            f" Got: {len(instr.split(Assembler.delimSymb))}")
        try:
            operands = None
            if expected_no_of_ops > 0:
                operands = [int(x.strip(), 16) for x in instr.split(",")]

                # Check if operands are in valid value range
                for limitation, operand in zip(op.value[1], operands):
                    if operand > limitation.value:
                        return (False, f"Invalid operand (value exceeds range): "\
                        f"{operand}")
            # Every validation check was passed. Return successfully
            return (True, self.__encode_instr(op, operands))
        except ValueError as ve:
            return (False, f"Invalid argument value: {str(ve).split(': ')[-1]}")

    def __encode_instr(self, op: Op, operands: List[int]) -> str:
        '''Encode/Assemble a single validated instruction.

        Return a String consisting of the assembled instruction.
        '''
        print(f"[DEBUG] Encode: <{op}> #{operands}#")
        machine_code = format(op.value[0], "x")
        # Handle the output order of the assembler instructions
        for output in op.value[2]:
            if output == OpType.ZER:
                machine_code += "0"
            else:
                # add the operand with formatting based on its type
                if op.value[1][output] == OpType.ADR:
                    machine_code += format(operands[output], "02x")
                else:
                    machine_code += format(operands[output], "x")
        return machine_code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("debug.bin", "r") as f:
        ass = Assembler(f.read())
        print("Translate: " + ass.translate())
        print("URL:")
        print("http://joeledstrom.github.io/brookshear-emu/#" + ass.get_last_translation())
        #print("Get Translate: " + ass.get_last_translation())
```

Comment: _The instruction set used by this implementation is based on a task from a friend's Computer Science course._ Do you happen to have a way of sharing that task? I would love to give this a try myself. That code currently isn't runnable, eh.

Comment: @AMC I‘ve uploaded the code to GitHub. The instruction set can be found in the ReadMe: https://github.com/DerReparator/Assembler-for-Brookshear-Machine A compatible machine can be found at the link in my question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall, looks very good and clean to me too, especially from a first poster. A few minor things:

PEP 8 prefers triple double quotes for docstrings. I don't particularly care but it's in the contract to point such things out. And, in general, it's a courtesy to reviewers to get your IDE/linter to fix such things before posting.

There are a few debateable comparisons to 0. I'm not sure that I greatly prefer "if expected_no_of_ops" to "if expected_no_of_ops > 0". However, "if not line" is definitely more idiomatic than "if len(line) == 0:"

Finally, I marginally prefer passing a stream rather than a string to Assembler:

```
 ass = Assembler(f.read()) 
 ... 
 for num, line in enumerate(self.code.split("\n"), 1):
```

would be easier as:

```
 ass = Assembler(f) 
 ... 
 for num, line in enumerate(self.code_stream, 1):
```

You can always use StringIO to go from string to stream (e.g. for testing)

Comment: Your suggestion regarding the usage of a _stream_ sounds very good. Thank you!